# Update a table with a value field in ANOTHER table, but selecting unique value from second based on timestamp

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have two tables (MatMast and ChangeLog) in an Access Database, where the common key is MatCode.  The tables look like this:

**MatMast**

MatCode (PK), CurrentStatus

10001, ACTIVE

10002, INACTIVE

10003, ACTIVE

**ChangeLog**

ChangeInstance (PK), MatCode, Status, TimeStamp

25452, 10001, ACTIVE, 19-Dec-2012 11:21 AM

25678, 10001, INACTIVE, 20-Dec-2012 06:45 PM

20296, 10002, ACTIVE, 20-Dec-2012 03:52 PM

My job now is to write an SQL Query in Access (not allowed to use VBA :( for this) to update the MatMast table into this:

**MatMast (After *proposed* update query)**

MatCode (PK), CurrentStatus

10001, INACTIVE     <== Picking up ChangeInstance 25678, which is the latest for 10001

10002, ACTIVE       <== Picking up ChangeInstance 20296, which is the ONLY rec for 10002

10003, ACTIVE       <== Unchanged, as there are no records for this in ChangeLog

Tried various approaches.  But, I am not able to write an update query to do this.  Please, Please help!

Regds,
SKB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention an assignment, so I suspect that the update is required so:

```
UPDATE matmast
       INNER JOIN (SELECT c.changeinstance,
                          c.matcode,
                          c.status,
                          c.TIMESTAMP
                   FROM   changelog c
                   WHERE  (( ( c.changeinstance ) IN
                             (SELECT TOP 1 changeinstance
                              FROM   changelog q
                              WHERE  q.matcode = c.matcode
                              ORDER  BY TIMESTAMP DESC,
                                        changeinstance) ))) x
               ON matmast.matcode = x.matcode
SET    matmast.currentstatus = x.status
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't vote up this answer, as I did not have enough reps :(

Comment: Do not worry about it, glad I could help :)